# Adding a submit button gives adjacent tag error

Tags: jsx, react-native

How can I add a submit button at the bottom of the `</Grid>`?

The way I am currently adding it shows the error:

```
'Adjacent-jsx  elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag'.
```

My code:

```
return (
  <Grid >
    <Col style={styles.main}>
      <Row size={5} style={styles.one}>
        <Text style={styles.hover}>
          eggwhgwr
        </Text>
        <Image source={require('./images/kl.png')} style={styles.imga} />
      </Row>
      <Row size={5} style={styles.two}>
        <Text style={styles.rack}>
          ewgy
        </Text>
        <Image source={require('./images/euru.png')} style={styles.imghos} />
      </Row>
      <Row size={5} style={styles.three}>
        <Text style={styles.doy}></Text>
        <Image source={require('./images/et.png')} style={styles.img} />
        `enter code here`
      </Row>
    </Col>
    <Col style={styles.maine}>
      <Row size={5} style={styles.four}>
        <Text style={styles.car}>
          Welcom
        </Text>
        <Image source={require('./images/eewt.png')} style={styles.imgcar} />
      </Row>
      <Row size={5} style={styles.five}>
        <Text style={styles.faq}>
          Fer
        </Text>
        <Image source={require('./images/uy87.png')} style={styles.imgfaq} />
      </Row>
      <Row size={5} style={styles.six}>
        <Text style={styles.info}>
          Info
        </Text>
        <Image source={require('./images/about.png')} style={styles.imgabout} />
      </Row> 
    </Col>
  </Grid>
);
```

Comment: Were you adding the submit button bellow `</Grid>`? If you were, you will need to wrap both the `<Grid>` and submit button elements in a `<div>` element in the return statement, as you can only ever have one element in a JSX statement.